# Conditional formatting - keep original conditional formatting but mask number as text

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a set of rates I have applied conditional formatting to in excel 2016, see screenshot below:
[image]

On top of this, I also have a conditional format that formats blank cells as  gray.

While these are rates, additionally I would like to mask rates in cases where their denominator is below 10 and replace the displayed value with "I" to indicate insufficient data, but still keep the original conditional formatted color displayed. Is there an efficient way to do this in excel 2016?

Comment: Not really. Since conditional formatting is base on the value in the cell, if the value changes, so does the formatting. There could be some elaborate workaround but it really won't be nice

Comment: that was my gut feeling. i was thinking i might just have to manually do everything in Illustrator, how would you do it?

Comment: Could you use a second condition to format the text the same colour as the cell? It does leave the value in the cell, but it "looks" blank

Comment: i can hide values by formatting them as ;;; (custom format), but i wanted to take it 1 step further by formatting them as "I" to serve as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround I discovered with the help of my coworkers.

- Take the table with conditional formatting in Excel
- Copy it all
- Open up a blank Microsoft Word document
- Paste the Excel table into Microsoft Word
- Select the whole table in Word and copy it
- Paste the table from Word back into Excel

The formatting might look a little clunky at first, but my conditional formatting was then locked in as the format and no longer conditional. This worked for my purposes; I was then able to apply additional conditional formatting on top of this table without issue.